# bootstrap 5 Responsive Collapsing Navbar remove image when collapsing

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with `Bootstrap 5.2.1` I have a simple Menu that collapsed.

Here is the main menu
[image: Main Menu]

Here is the menu when collapses
[image: Menu collapses]

When I open the popup menu it is shown like this

[image: Popup Menu]

The problem is that the menu has an `Tyrian-icon` Image.

What I would like to do is to remove the image when the popup menu appears and just leave the text `Logout` and `Home`

Is that possible?

Thanks

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <div class="float-end">
          <a href="@Url.Action(" Logout ","Auth ")" class="nav-link text-dark py-1 px-3" title="Logout">
            <span style="padding-left:5px" class="hqy-logout icon"></span><br /><span>Logout</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <div class="float-end">
          <a href="@Url.Action(" Logout ","Auth ")" class="nav-link text-dark px-4 py-1" title="Home">
            <span class="hqy-home icon px-1"></span><br /><span>Home</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format. It's a bit of a mess. Don't add tags.

Comment: I've converted your code to a demo. Does it show the problem? Please revise as needed.

Comment: I just added an image showing the problem.. thanks

Comment: We can't debug images. Please make the _demo_ show the problem.

Comment: `d-none d-sm-block`?